# How to Pass Data Value between Functions?

Tags: javascript, function, webpack, async-await, module

I am making a simple weather app using vanilla Javascript which uses the openweathermap api. I am using webpack. My issue is I cannot figure out how to pass the fetched data values I need (such as current temperature) between my different functions.

There are two files - index.js and main.js. *Please explain how to make **${finalTempRender}** inside of **main()** returns the correct value instead of undefined as it does now*. I have tried various routes which have all failed but I have left the code as is anyway in case I was on the right trail.

Thank you.

Code below:
Index.js

```
import header from './header';
import main from './main';
import { getWeatherData } from './main';

const insertPoint = document.getElementById('content');

export async function fetchCurrentForecast(location) {
  let chosenLocation;
  let currentTemp;
  let currentWeather;
  let finalTemp;
  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${location}&APPID=d00f39ffd7b70efa9fb08ef14fe29fa5`
    );
    const data = await response.json();

    currentTemp = data.main.temp - 237.15;
    finalTemp = currentTemp.toFixed(2);
    chosenLocation = data.name;
    currentWeather = data.weather[0].main;

    console.log(currentTemp, currentWeather, chosenLocation, finalTemp);
    getWeatherData(finalTemp, chosenLocation, currentWeather);
    return finalTemp, chosenLocation, currentWeather;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

fetchCurrentForecast('paris, fr');

insertPoint.appendChild(header());
insertPoint.appendChild(main());
```

Main.js

```
import Sunny from '../src/images/sunny.jpg';
import { fetchCurrentForecast } from './index';

let finalTempRender;
export function getWeatherData(finalTemp, currentWeather, chosenLocation) {
  console.log(finalTemp, currentWeather, chosenLocation);
  finalTempRender = finalTemp;
  return finalTempRender, currentWeather, chosenLocation;
}

function main() {
  const main = document.createElement('main');
  const sunny = new Image();
  sunny.src = Sunny;
  main.innerHTML = `
  <div className="forecast_Container">
  <img src=${Sunny} alt="" />
  <h4>${finalTempRender} F</h4>
  </div>
`;
  console.log(fetchCurrentForecast('paris, fr'));
  return main;
}

export default main;
```

Comment: What do you think `return finalTempRender, currentWeather, chosenLocation;` returns? You're wrong

Comment: What is `fetchCurrentForecast` ... it's not exported from index yet you try to import it from index

Comment: I was trying to return the values to see if I could access the values somehow which is my current problem. fetchCurrentForecast is exported as an async function from index.js into main.js. 

Do you have a suggestion for how to answer my question? That is, making finalTempRender return the fetched value instead of undefined?

Comment: sure but exactly what do you think `return finalTempRender, currentWeather, chosenLocation;` returns

Comment: I think it returns the values. However then I need to call that function, which I tried to do, and then use the values but I have not been able to get those values where I need them, inside of main(). I know in React I could just pass the value down as props or hold it in some sort of state but using vanilla javascript I am having a hard time figuring out how to do what is very straight forward in React (probably vanilla JS too but I am stuck on the issue). Could you please tell me how make finalTempRender return the fetched value instead of undefined inside of main.()?

Comment: `I think it returns the values` what have you observed? it returns a single value

Comment: I think you are being very rude. I am trying to get better and you keep poking a stick in my eye. I have observed hours worth of failed attempts which I should not have to explain to you to receive help on a platform designed to receive answers to questions, not questions to questions. There are four different methods made to try and gain the fetched value into main() where I need it to display to UI, all have failed - including returning the values you harp on. So, please just tell me how to mane finalTempRender show the value and not undefined and I will understand the rest. Thank you.

Comment: No, I'm suggesting that you do things to understand what your code is doing. Sorry if think I'm rude by trying to teach you how to debug your code